# jQuery $.ajax POST Multiple Select Selections

Tags: jquery, ajax, multiple-select

I have a multipe select as part of my imput form and I would like to submit it's selected values via jQuery AJAX.

I've tried to use the following syntax.

```
$('#multipleselect').val().join('|');
```

That works, bu the problem I am having is that the user is not required to select anything from the multiple select. If they don't I get an error because you cannot join a null object.

Any Suggestions?

Also keep in mind that there are other values being submitted. For example:

```
data: "name=" + $("#name").val() + "&multipleselect=" + $("#multipleselect").val().join('|');
```

Comment: Just check if it is null before you join it

Comment: can I do that in the data string? or do I have to assign it to a var?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

```
var data = $('form').serialize()
```

Comment: That is another problem I am having. I am .load() - ing the form into a jQuery UI dialog and I cannot seem to get the serialized form when using an alert for testing.

Comment: @MikeGeorge note that your form elements must have name attributes.

Comment: Oh, I thought the form it self just needed a name. I'll go try this, if it works I'll mark your answer. Thanks!

Comment: No, if you're using something like jQuery DataTables, you need to build an 'object', not a 'string'. It gives you a data object, which you can add values to, and that's it.  And you cannot add multiple keys with the same name to this object, because plain Objects don't support that. So short of manually constructing the absolute final data string with multiple values with the same key (which is basically what serializeArray is doing), you cannot take advantage of any other kind of processing, such as the complex processing DataTables does to include keys of the form 'column[i][prop]=value'.

Comment: @Triynko You can't send an object directly via http protocol. You should pass a string. Nowadays mostly JSON is used. JSON is a **string representation** of a data type and Datatables which uses jQuery Ajax methods behind the scenes also sends a _string_ as the request body to server . If you pass an object to jQuery Ajax methods, these methods convert the passed datum to JSON before sending the request. The way plugins use data is a different topic.